# Using LINQ to query huge CSV and Excel

Tags: c#, sql, excel, linq, csv

I am trying to find ways to access huge Excel or CSV files and perform Aggregation operations like Sum, count and certain SQL like operations like Select, group by etc.
I am aware of the fact that LINQ can help me do this. I prefer to use C#. My questions are:

1) Will the data from excel or CSV be loaded on to memory while performing any queries? All files are around 12GB. The reason i am asking is i dont want the app to hang.

2) Can i create a Form application, where in i have a TextArea which lists all the columns of CSV/Excel. User is given option to select any columns from the TextArea. I am planning to have SQL options like SELECT, GROUP BY, SUM, AVERAGE and many other. User can select one of these and internally i build query using LINQ and get the results. The results can be stored in a text file.

I am not sure whether this is do-able. Please suggest me on this. I am new to using LINQ. 
If this is not possible through LINQ, can you please suggest other methods to do this efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it and it fails?

Comment: Are the excel files really excel files or just text/csv files with an extension `.xls`/`.xlsx`?

Comment: Answers: 1) It depends on query you will write. 2) If you are good in programming - you can, otherwise you can't. Being serious - please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Might want to consider loading the file into a DB as that is designed for doing queries.

Answer (score 3):

Memory isn't your issue - performance is.

I wholeheartedly agree with the comments about loading this into a proper database that will index rows, etc. to make it MUCH more efficient. With that said, performing the sorts of queries you describe IS possible and straightforward (if highly inadvisable) by reading the CSV directly.

I thought it would be fun to test [LINQtoCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library) at this task.

Not having any ready made HUGE csv files to hand I just generated one with the following headers:

```
"row,Guid,Grouping1,Grouping2,Metric1,Metric2"
```

where`row` is the row number, `Guid` is just a random guid `Grouping1` is a random int between 0 and 49, `Grouping2` is a random int between 0 and 50,000 and `Metric1` & `Metric2` are random ints and doubles respectively. Basically just some random data.

I then generated a 7Gb+ file with 99999999 rows...(I was aiming for 100,000,000 but hit my zero-indexing blind-spot somewhere!)

So the good news is LINQtoCSV will happily parse this bad boy without having to load the file into memory. Just create the class represented by a row in the csv:

```
    class Entry
    {
        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 1, Name="row")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2)]
        public string Guid { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 3)]
        public int Grouping1 { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 4)]
        public int Grouping2 { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 5)]
        public int Metric1 { get; set; }

        [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 6)]
        public double Metric2 { get; set; }
    }
```

then read the entries into an `IEnumerable`:

```
    IEnumerable<Entry> ReadEntries()
    {
        CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };

        CsvContext ctx = new CsvContext();

        return ctx.Read<Entry>("test.csv", inputFileDescription);
    }
```

and away you go.

You now have a fully functioning IEnumerable ready to query with all the GroupBy(), Select(), Sum(), Count() etc. and all the other SQL-like fun of Linq.

Just one small problem....

it is NOT fast!

Using this simple LINQtoCSV set up, I ran 3 simple linq queries in parallel

1. count all entries
2. Count all entries where Group1==1
3. Sum Metric2 where Group2==1

using this code:

```
    static IEnumerable<Entry> entries;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        entries = ReadEntries();

        var tasks = new List<Task> {timeEntryCount,timeEntryCountWhereG1_equals_1,timeMetric2SumWhereG2_equals_1};

        tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start());

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("Entry count took " + timeEntryCount.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("Entry count where G1==1 took " + timeEntryCountWhereG1_equals_1.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("Metric1 sum where G2==1 took " + timeMetric2SumWhereG2_equals_1.Result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Task<TimeSpan> timeMetric2SumWhereG2_equals_1 = new Task<TimeSpan>(() =>
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        double sum = entries
            .Where(e => e.Grouping2 == 1)
            .Sum(e=>e.Metric2);
        Console.WriteLine("sum: " + sum);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        return end - start;
    },TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    static Task<TimeSpan> timeEntryCountWhereG1_equals_1 = new Task<TimeSpan>(() =>
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        long count = entries
            .Where(e=>e.Grouping1==1)
            .Count();
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("countG1: " + count);
        return end - start;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    static Task<TimeSpan> timeEntryCount = new Task<TimeSpan>(() =>
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        long count = entries.Count();
        Console.WriteLine("CountAll: " + count);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        return end - start;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Now admittedly this dodgy parallelism is not the BEST way to go about testing this but I was just shooting from the hip.

However the results are really very ugly on my *reasonably* quick SSD equiped laptop:

> ```
> countG1: 2003023
> CountAll: 99999999
> sum: 1236810295.16543
> Entry count took 00:25:26.3767852
> Entry count where G1==1 took 00:24:41.9855814
> Metric1 sum where G2==1 took 00:25:30.9080960
> ```

That's roughly 25 mins to query the file. If this doesn't persuede you to get this into a properly indexed database nothing will!